# Service Fabric Actor Reminder Where Period More than Default (60 minutes)

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful, service-fabric-actor

This is probably a very trivial question but just want to ask (after doing my initial search). The persistent SF actor gets garbage collected after 60 minutes(default) of being idle(not used). Will the `ReceiveReminderAsync` still gets called if I have a reminder created with a period of more than 60 minutes ?

Comment: Not at all a trivial question! I can not say for sure as I have yet to experiment with reminders but I believe so, yes. I posted a similar question before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117425/service-fabric-reminders

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm wrong, the actorservice will spin up a new actor as necessary. See this briliant answer with sample code here [Service Fabric Reminders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117425/service-fabric-reminders)

Answer (score 0):

Reminders are a mechanism to trigger persistent callbacks on an actor at specified times. They are similar to timers, but unlike timers reminders are triggered under all circumstances until the actor explicitly unregisters them or the actor is deleted. Actors are triggered across actor deactivations and failovers because the Actors runtime persists information about the actor's reminders.